# How to compare the JSON object with the same key in the same JSON in Android Studio in Java?

Tags: java, android, json

I am new to this. I am exploring a timetable Android library in GitHub. I can now save a JSON of the class data and I have a JSON that stores the data of a simple timetable.
The JSON string is as below:

```
String data:
{
        "sticker":[ {
                    "idx":2,
                    "schedule":[{
                                    "classTitle": "Image Processing",
                                    "classPlace": "DK3",
                                    "professorName":"John",
                                    "day":4,
                                    "startTime" :{"hour":8,"minute":0},
                                    "endTime"   :{"hour":10,"minute":0}
                                }]
                    },
                    {
                    "idx":4,
                    "schedule":[{
                                    "classTitle":"Digital Signal Processing",
                                    "classPlace":"DK10",
                                    "professorName":"Billy",
                                    "day":0,
                                    "startTime" :{"hour":8,"minute":0},
                                    "endTime"   :{"hour":10,"minute":0}
                                }]
                    },
                    {
                    "idx":6,
                    "schedule":[{
                                    "classTitle":"Data Analytics",
                                    "classPlace":"DK6",
                                    "professorName":"Susan",
                                    "day":2,
                                    "startTime" :{"hour":15,"minute":0},
                                    "endTime"   :{"hour":17,"minute":0}
                                }]
                    }
                ]
    }
```

I would like to check if there is any class in the JSON overlaps each other's class hour. As an example, class A and class B is on the same day and class B starts in the interval of class A. How do I check the conditions of the classes in order to find out the classes that overlaps and display all the information of both the schedule of the classes.

Below are the Java classes of the timetable library that may be related.

This is the **Sticker.java**.

```
package com.github.tlaabs.timetableview;

import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sticker implements Serializable {
    private ArrayList<TextView> view;
    private ArrayList<Schedule> schedules;

    public Sticker() {
        this.view = new ArrayList<TextView>();
        this.schedules = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
    }

    public void addTextView(TextView v){
        view.add(v);
    }

    public void addSchedule(Schedule schedule){
        schedules.add(schedule);
    }

    public ArrayList<TextView> getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public ArrayList<Schedule> getSchedules() {
        return schedules;
    }
}
```

This is the **Schedule.java**.

```
package com.github.tlaabs.timetableview;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Schedule implements Serializable {
    static final int MON = 0;
    static final int TUE = 1;
    static final int WED = 2;
    static final int THU = 3;
    static final int FRI = 4;
    static final int SAT = 5;
    static final int SUN = 6;

    String classTitle="";
    String classPlace="";
    String professorName="";
    private int day = 0;
    private Time startTime;
    private Time endTime;

    public Schedule() {
        this.startTime = new Time();
        this.endTime = new Time();
    }

    public String getProfessorName() {
        return professorName;
    }

    public void setProfessorName(String professorName) {
        this.professorName = professorName;
    }

    public String getClassTitle() {
        return classTitle;
    }

    public void setClassTitle(String classTitle) {
        this.classTitle = classTitle;
    }

    public String getClassPlace() {
        return classPlace;
    }

    public void setClassPlace(String classPlace) {
        this.classPlace = classPlace;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public Time getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(Time startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public Time getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(Time endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: define a method in Schedule that determines has overlaps or not. `hasOverlap(Schedule obj)` then check each Schedule with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know any library that can do this, but you can do it yourself.

First, you can compare the days of the week of classes to know which classes you have to compare (you are going to compare the classes given on the same day).

Then, when you have the classes of a day, you have to compare the hours of these classes.

```
String startTime = "08:00";
String endTime= "10:00";

String timeToCompare="08:30";

String[] parts = startTime .split(":");
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(parts[0]));
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));

parts = endTime.split(":");
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(parts[0]));
cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));

parts = timeToCompare.split(":");
Calendar cal3 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(parts[0]));
cal3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
```

With this code, you create the Calendar object of the start and end time and of the time to compare.

Then, you compare the timeToCompare with both times to know if timeToCompare is between startTime and endTime:

```
if (cal1.before(cal3) && cal2.after(cal3)) {
    System.out.println("timeToCompare between startTime and endTime");
}
```

So, if you have class A and class B, you can compare startTime of class B with startTime and endTime of class A and endTime of class B with startTime and endTime of class A. If any time of class B is between startTime and endTime of class A, the classes overlap.

I hope I have understood your problem and this solution serves you.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Now I have startTime in the form of {"hour":8,"minute":0}, how do I turn it into "08:00"?

Comment: I guess you have serialized the json, so the simplest option is that you create a function in your Time.java class (for example, call timeString) that return something like that:

public String timeString(){
 return String.valueOf(hour)+":"+String.valueOf(minute)
}

With this function you convert the variables hour and minute to String and concat with ":".